# 2 Activity in one screen

Tags: android

Is it possible to have 2 different activities in one screen with both having their own layout and class in android studio? What I mean with 2 different activity is, 1 taking half of the screen while the other activity takes the other half. Thank you very much!

Comment: I know what you want, to do that you got to use two fragments inside the same activity

Comment: Watch this video and its playlist https://youtu.be/tfC8J8AeQkw

Comment: use fragment instead of activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically enter multi-window mode in Android N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567799/programmatically-enter-multi-window-mode-in-android-n)